# How access typscript enum values?

Tags: typescript

How can I access values of an enum correctly? Or is it just a type and one should not do it?

```
enum Days{
  monday= "monday",
  sunday= "sunday",
}

console.log(Days["monday"])
```

Error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type Days
```

Comment: Did you check this out? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error](https://tsplay.dev/mx8J8m).  What exactly is the issue here?  And is there a reason you've given the keys and values the same names?  That just makes talking about the enum confusing "Do you mean `"monday"` the key or `"monday"` the value?" so maybe `enum Days { MONDAY = "mon", TUESDAY = "tue" }` or something.  But anyway there's no error in your code so this needs  an [edit] somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(Days[Days.monday]);
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? (Also, OP wants the values, not the keys)